# Microsoft Azure Virtual Networking

Tags: networking, cloud, azure

I have created a Virtual Network in Azure following the steps in the [tutorial](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/create-a-virtual-network/). I then create a VM using the Windows 2008 R2 image and select the FrontEndSubnet (10.4.3.0/24) for the VM. (Following this [tutorial](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/add-a-vm-to-a-virtual-network/)) When I remote into the VM and take a look at the network properties the Network Status says identifying. I run an ipconfig and the default gateway is 10.4.3.1 and it times out. I have tried both with creating a gateway and connecting to my local network as well as with just a Azure Virtual Network and have the same results. Any help would be appreciated.

---